# how to integrate matlab compiled code into c++ in Debian system

Tags: c++, linux, matlab-compiler

I have been trying to use Matlab compiler SDK to packaging my Matlab program as C++ shared library in Debian system. I have got the folder including test.c, test.h, test.so (test is my Matlab program name), and I have installed the Matlab_runtime in the Debian system. I have set the variables LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ and _ XAPPLRESDIR_ as required in the readme.txt _ ***( _ *replace MCR_ROOT by the directory where the MATLAB Runtime is installed on the target machine.
    (1) Set the environment variable XAPPLRESDIR to this value:
        MCR_ROOT/v91/X11/app-defaults
    (2) If the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is undefined, set it to the concatenation of the following strings:
        MCR_ROOT/v91/runtime/glnxa64:
        MCR_ROOT/v91/bin/glnxa64:
        MCR_ROOT/v91/sys/os/glnxa64:
        MCR_ROOT/v91/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64*_)***
    . 
    I edit my main.cpp include test.h. when I try to compile the main.cpp use _ *gcc main.cpp -o main*_, I got the error as follows:
    ***In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
    test.h:15:22: fetal error: mclmcrrt.h: No such file or directory
    #include "mclmcrrt.h"***

```
I know that mclmcrrt.h is in the package of Matlab_runtime, it means I failed to link to the library of Matlab_runtime. Anybody knows what should I do to make my main.cpp compile successfully? I tried two days to work on how to connect to the Matlab_runtime library, but still failed. I am a beginner to linux. Great thanks if anyone can help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compilation problem, not linkage. Your compiler does not know where `mclmcrrt.h` is. Please help it find it by telling it where it is:

`gcc -I<the_folder_where_mclmcrrt.h_lives_in> ...`

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, now my code can find the head files, but now I met new problems as follows:

Comment: /tmp/cc8IP6a1.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `mclmcrInitialize_proxy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `mclInitializeApplication_860_proxy'
main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `testInitialize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `mlfTest'
main.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `testTerminate'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `mclTerminateApplication_proxy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I know this should be the linking problem to MCR. my code is :
gcc -L/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/extern/lib/glnxa64  -L/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/bin/glnxa64 -I/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/extern/include  -I./test -lstdc++ -lgcc_s main.cpp -o main . How should I do to link MCR successfully?

Comment: put main.cpp BEFORE the libraries. `main.cpp -I./test -lstdc++ -lgcc_s`

Comment: Hi Shloim, thanks for quick response,I have tried what you suggested, but it doesn't really make any difference, and gives the same errors. Any other suggestions?